# Reading imported csv files in sqlite from python

Tags: python, database, csv, sqlite

I have imported a csv file to sqlite using the command line window. My table exists under the name consumer_complaints when I search for it in sqlite. Now, I'm trying to see this file via Python by using the below command:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect("consumer_complaints.sqlite")

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM consumer_complaints")

    rows=cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

However, it gives me an error saying the table doesn't exist. What may be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure consumer_complaints is a table within the consumer_complaints database?  Is your current directory the one in which that database is in?

Comment: where should I define the directory @BradSolomon

Comment: You can either pass the full (absolute) path to `lite.connect()`, or use `import os` --> `os.chdir('path/to/folder')` where folder contains that database

Comment: I have tried lite.connect("C:/users/aa/consumer.complaints.csv"). However that didn't work

Comment: You can't connect to a csv file.  Is this a .sqlite or .csv file?

Comment: I have imported the csv file in sqlite command window. just changed the lite.connect("C:/Users/ali.yagmur.aydinli/Downloads/consumer_complaints.sqlite") still it says file not found

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to help you then without knowing what your directory looks like.  Your syntax seems correct in your last comment here.

Comment: Try this: `os.path.isfile("C:/Users/ali.yagmur.aydinli/Downloads/consumer_complaints.sqlite")`.  That tells you True?

Comment: It runs without giving an error

Comment: It should return True or False.. which one?

Comment: it gives true. so I guess the file path is correct

Comment: the error is exactly like this sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: consumer_complaints

Comment: I think you may be confusing a database with the tables within it.